# Clojure function evaluation

Tags: java, clojure

I was searching for a Clojure logarithm function and concluded there really isn't one for v1.3+. What took me so long to invoke `Math/log` was this:

```
user=> Math/log

CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find static field: log in class java.lang.Math, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0:0)
```

I tried variations like `(use 'java.lang.Math)` and so forth. It wasn't until I tried an example that I found it's there after all:

```
user=> (Math/log 10)
2.302585092994046
```

This must be by design, but what is the reason?

Comment: `Math/log` is a static method. You are trying to access it as if it were a static variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A static method imported from Java is not a Clojure function or any other kind of Clojure object. The compiler reports any misfit as a missing field, even where the context is looking for a function. All of these ...

```
Math/log
(Math/log)
(map Math/log (range 1 5))
```

... produce such errors.

For a corresponding Clojure function:

- `inc` returns the function;
- `(inc)` reports `... wrong number of args(0) ...`;
- `(map inc (range 1 5))` returns `(2 3 4 5)`.

You can wrap a Java method as a Clojure one:

```
(defn log [x] (Math/log x))
```

... getting the expected result:

```
(map log (range 1 5))
;(0.0 0.6931471805599453 1.0986122886681098 1.3862943611198906)
```

The Clojure [Java Interop](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-The%20Dot%20special%20form-(memfn%20method-name%20arg-names*)) page recommends

`(map #(Math/log %) (range 1 5))`

... in such cases.

Answer (score 4):

Clojure provides some forms for interoperating with Java classes, methods, and fields. When you access static field in a class, you can do it like this:

```
user=> Integer/MAX_VALUE
;=> 2147483647
user=> Math/PI
;=> 3.141592653589793
```

And when you want to invoke static method, you can use the following form

```
user=> (Math/log 10)
;=> 2.302585092994046
user=> (Math/sin 1)
;=> 0.8414709848078965
```

When you try to evaluate just `Math/log`, clojure think it's static field, which is not true.

```
user=> Math/log

;=> CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find static field: log in class java.lang.Math, compiling:(/private/var/folders/jh/q738l9dn0hxg0vvwbty7m5hw0000gp/T/form-init145007798854806400.clj:1:5845)
```

You can see it from the error message(`Unable to find static field:...`) that the clojure REPL try to find static field `log` from `Math` class, then failed.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, one uses parentheses to invoke a function:

```
println("hi");
```

Clojure also uses parentheses to invoke a function, but with a different placement:

```
(println "hi")
```

In either Java or Clojure, just typing:

```
println
```

is an error, because you don't have the parentheses to indicate a function call.

In your first example, you use the name of the function Math/log, but you had no parentheses to tell the REPL that you wanted to invoke a function.

Also, in Java, parentheses can indicate either a function call or a grouping operator:

```
println(2 + (3 + 4))
```

In Clojure, parentheses ***only*** indicate function calls, and ***never*** indicating simple grouping.

Comment: In Clojure typing `println` is not an error. It just evaluates to the function itself.

Comment: In clojure functions are also data (symbols) of type IFn, which is why you don't get an error. Java methods do not share this property though.